# Port Forwarding on Cisco ASA 5510

Tags: cisco-asa, port-forwarding

I have an EDI server behind a Cisco ASA 5510 version 8.2(1). Currently our EDI server sends over documents to our trading partners and they will look for our URL in this format *http://1.1.1.1:1000*. Looking at a wireshark capture, I've noticed the source port will change for each delivery. This is not a big deal and has worked fine so far, but now one of our trading partners is requiring us to use one specific source port for data delivery.

I would assume I need to create some form of port forwarding in the ASA to accomplish this. Something along these lines...

```
object network STATIC-PAT
host 1.1.1.1
nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 1000
access-list OUTSIDE-IN permit tcp any object STATIC-PAT eq 1000
```

Would this be an acceptable configuration for my dilemma?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration you posted is for the 8.3 or newer versions of ASA. Since you are using a version of 8.2(1) you can try something like this:

```
static (inside,outside) tcp interface 1000 1.1.1.1 1000 netmask 255.255.255.255
access-list OUTSIDE-IN permit tcp any interface outside eq 1000
```

A simple search will provide you many articles on how to translate config between pre and post 8.3 config.(https://www.auvik.com/franklymsp/blog/migrating-cisco-asa-firewall-configuration/)